# PlatformException(error, invalid pointerIndex for MotionEvent) on AndroidViewSurface of Flutter

Tags: flutter

I got an issue when I use the AndroidViewSurface for Map View.
I have a bottom sheet on the Map. And when I'm dragging the sheet, it is happened if I touched the Map View.

I've tried handling touch events in the Android native code, but this is not a problem. My guess is that the problem could be with AndroidViewSurface. I'm at a loss as to how to deal with this. can you help?

```
[!] Flutter (Channel unknown, 3.3.9, on macOS 12.5.1 21G83 darwin-arm, locale ko-KR)
    ! Flutter version 3.3.9 on channel unknown at /Users/khkong/development/flutter3
    ! Upstream repository unknown
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.62.0)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

```
 return PlatformViewLink(
        viewType: 'plugins.flutter.io/maps',
        surfaceFactory:
            (BuildContext context, PlatformViewController controller) {
          return AndroidViewSurface(
            controller: controller as AndroidViewController,
            hitTestBehavior: PlatformViewHitTestBehavior.opaque,
            gestureRecognizers: <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>{}
              ..add(Factory<PanGestureRecognizer>(() => PanGestureRecognizer()))
              ..add(Factory<ScaleGestureRecognizer>(
                  () => ScaleGestureRecognizer()))
              ..add(Factory<TapGestureRecognizer>(() => TapGestureRecognizer()))
              ..add(Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(() => EagerGestureRecognizer()))
              ..add(Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
                  () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer())),
          );
        },
        onCreatePlatformView: (PlatformViewCreationParams params) {
          return PlatformViewsService.initSurfaceAndroidView(
            id: params.id,
            viewType: 'plugins.flutter.io/edp_maps',
            layoutDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            creationParams: creationParams,
            creationParamsCodec: const StandardMessageCodec(),
          )
            ..addOnPlatformViewCreatedListener(params.onPlatformViewCreated)
            ..addOnPlatformViewCreatedListener(onPlatformViewCreated)
            ..create();
        },
      );
```

```
PlatformException(error, invalid pointerIndex 1 for MotionEvent { action=POINTER_UP(1), id[0]=0, x[0]=864.844, y[0]=1468.36, eventTime=32909910000000, downTime=32909877000000, deviceId=4, source=TOUCHSCREEN, displayId=0, eventId=-1041895496}, null, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid pointerIndex 1 for MotionEvent { action=POINTER_UP(1), id[0]=0, x[0]=864.844, y[0]=1468.36, eventTime=32909910000000, downTime=32909877000000, deviceId=4, source=TOUCHSCREEN, displayId=0, eventId=-1041895496}
    at android.view.MotionEvent.nativeGetPointerId(Native Method)
    at android.view.MotionEvent.getPointerId(MotionEvent.java:2842)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3024)
    at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController$1.i(SourceFile:12)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.k(SourceFile:19)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.onMethodCall(SourceFile:7)
    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.a(SourceFile:2)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.l(SourceFile:2)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.m(SourceFile:2)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.i(Unknown Source:0)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.a.run(Unknown Source:12)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8741)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
)
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:653)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:296)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      AndroidViewController.sendMotionEvent (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:850)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      AndroidViewController.dispatchPointerEvent (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:950)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

```
PlatformException(error, pointerIndex out of range, null, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range
    at android.view.MotionEvent.nativeGetPointerId(Native Method)
    at android.view.MotionEvent.getPointerId(MotionEvent.java:2760)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3631)
    at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController$1.i(SourceFile:12)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.k(SourceFile:19)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.onMethodCall(SourceFile:7)
    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.a(SourceFile:2)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.l(SourceFile:2)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.m(SourceFile:2)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.i(Unknown Source:0)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.a.run(Unknown Source:12)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
)
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:653)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:296)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      AndroidViewController.sendMotionEvent (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:850)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      AndroidViewController.dispatchPointerEvent (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:950)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I tried as follows. but they were not solutions.

- Handling the touch event listener on Android Views.
- Add gestureRecognizers in AndroidViewSurface.